# UCARP: prevent the original master from taking over the VIP when it comes back after failure?

Tags: centos, keepalived, carp, virtual-ip, ucarp

[Keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) can do this by combining the `nopreempt` option and the `BACKUP` state on the both nodes:

- [Prevent VRRP Master from becoming Master once it has failed](https://serverfault.com/questions/44122/prevent-vrrp-master-from-becoming-master-once-it-has-failed)
- [Prevent master to fall back to master after failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/396839/prevent-master-to-fall-back-to-master-after-failure)

How about the [UCARP](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/ucarp)?

```
Name       : ucarp
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 1.5.2
Release    : 1.el5.rf
Size       : 81 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : Common Address Redundancy Protocol (CARP) for Unix
URL        : http://www.ucarp.org/
License    : BSD
Description: UCARP allows a couple of hosts to share common virtual IP addresses in order
           : to provide automatic failover. It is a portable userland implementation of the
           : secure and patent-free Common Address Redundancy Protocol (CARP, OpenBSD's
           : alternative to the patents-bloated VRRP).
           : Strong points of the CARP protocol are: very low overhead, cryptographically
           : signed messages, interoperability between different operating systems and no
           : need for any dedicated extra network link between redundant hosts.
```

If I don't use the `--preempt` option and set the `--advskew` to the same value, both nodes become master.

**`/etc/sysconfig/carp/vip-010.conf`**

```
# Virtual IP configuration file for UCARP
# The number (from 001 to 255) in the name of the file is the identifier
# $Id: vip-001.conf.example 1527 2004-07-09 15:23:54Z dude $

# Set the same password on all mamchines sharing the same virtual IP
PASSWORD="pa$$w0rd"

# You are required to have an IPADDR= line in the configuration file for
# this interface (so no DHCP allowed)
BIND_INTERFACE="eth0"

# Do *NOT* use a main interface for the virtual IP, use an ethX:Y alias
# with the corresponding /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX:Y file
# already configured and ith ONBOOT=no
VIP_INTERFACE="eth0:0"

# If you have extra options to add, see "ucarp --help" output
# (the lower the "-k <val>" the higher priority and "-P" to become master ASAP)
OPTIONS="-z -k 255"
```

**`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`**

```
DEVICE=eth0:0
ONBOOT=no
BOOTPROTO=
IPADDR=192.168.6.8
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
USERCTL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
```

**node 1:**

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:9b:8e:af:a7:69 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.6.192/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.6.8/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global secondary eth0:0
    inet6 fe80::c49b:8eff:feaf:a769/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**node 2:**

```
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:48:f7:0f:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.6.38/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global eth1
    inet 192.168.6.8/24 brd 192.168.6.255 scope global secondary eth1:0
    inet6 fe80::230:48ff:fef7:f81/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 2):

For UCARP, I think the trick is to start it in "neutral" mode using the `--neutral` flag, so that it doesn't automatically assume the master role or try anything upon start. Looking at one of my setups, here's the full command line. Perhaps `--neutral` applies because we have upscripts and downscripts applied at startup and shutdown, but it's worth a try.

`/path/to/ucarp0 -v 42 -p kitteh0 --interface=bond0 -a 192.168.100.250 -s 192.168.100.172 -b 5 -r 3 --upscript=/path/to/ucarp/upscript0 --downscript=/path/to/ucarp/downscript0 --neutral -z -B`

Comment: I also paid attention to this flag but I think it has different meaning: _the `--neutral` (`-n`) switch causes ucarp to not run the downscript
when it changes from the INIT state to the BACKUP state_. Is the second server started with the same options as the first server? I've tried `OPTIONS="-b 3 -r 5 -n -z"`, but nothing changes: both server become the master. If I started the second server with advertisement frequency (`-b`) greater than the first one, the VIP fail back to the original master.

Comment: Hmm... That's how it was explained to me here. I'll ask around.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the ucarp clusters (which i inherited) ever switching back by themselves.

They are indeed set to preempt=no.